# What is the correct way to get result for this POST method json API?

Tags: python, json, post

I'm a beginner in coding and I try to find a working solution to get the result of this JSON API

```
curl --location --request POST 'https://proxy.airgateway.net/v1.1/AirShopping' \
--header 'Content-Type: application/json' \
--header 'AG-Providers: BA' \
--header 'Authorization: {{AG-Authorization}}' \
--data-raw '{
  "metadata": {
    "country": "DE",
    "currency": "EUR",
    "locale": "de_DE"
  },
  "originDestinations": [
    {
      "departure": {
        "airportCode": "LHR",
        "date": "{{flight_date}}"
      },
      "arrival": {
        "airportCode": "MAD"
      }
    }
  ],
  "preferences": {
    "cabin": ["2"],
    "nonStop": false
  },
  "travelers": {
    "ADT": 2,
    "CHD": 0,
    "INF": 0
  }
}'
```

Here is the python code i'm trying with having the JSON data inside my request.json file but i'm lost with the hearders of the API

```
import requests
import json

AirShopping = 'https://proxy.airgateway.net/v1.1/AirShopping'

file = open('C:\\request.json','r')
json_input = file.read()
request_json = json.loads(json_input)


response = requests.post(AirShopping, request_json)
print(response.content)
```

thanks,

Mat

Answer (score 1):

Find an example below regarding the usage of headers in requests.
Note: I skipped the file loading part for convenience. This example fails with an authorization error for me which is fine since I did not provide an auth token. I think you can work it out based on this:

```
import requests
import json

AirShopping = 'https://proxy.airgateway.net/v1.1/AirShopping'

request_json = {
  "metadata": {
    "country": "DE",
    "currency": "EUR",
    "locale": "de_DE"
  },
  "originDestinations": [
    {
      "departure": {
        "airportCode": "LHR",
        "date": "{{flight_date}}"
      },
      "arrival": {
        "airportCode": "MAD"
      }
    }
  ],
  "preferences": {
    "cabin": ["2"],
    "nonStop": False
  },
  "travelers": {
    "ADT": 2,
    "CHD": 0,
    "INF": 0
  }
}

auth_token = "your-auth-token"

headers = {'content-type': 'application/json', 'AG-Providers': 'BA', 'Authorization': auth_token}


response = requests.post(AirShopping, data=request_json, headers=headers)
print(response.content)
```